# Wrong display of HTML email in Outlook

Tags: html, email, outlook, html-email, outlook-2010

I have the following code for an HTML email:

```
<div style="background-color:red;max-width:600px;height:140px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">

<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/140x99" height="140" width="99" style="height:140px;width:99px;display:block;border:0;float:right;margin:0px;padding:0px;">

<p style="margin:0;font-size:30px;font-weight:700;padding-left:10px;margin-top:0px;padding-top:10px;">This is an important example header!</p>

</div>
```

I expect the HTML to get rendered like this:

[image]

The text is on the left side, the image is on the right side and has the same height as the red parent element.

I tested this with all 86 e-mail renderers of `Email On Acid`. The HTML code gets rendered correctly on almost all email clients.

But there's a wrong display on the following e-mail clients:

```
Outlook Office 356 (Windows 10)
Outlook 2007 (Windows 7)
Outlook 2010 (Windows 7)
Outlook 2013 (Windows 7)
Outlook 2016 (Windows 10)
Outlook 2019 (Windows 10)
```

I get the following output:

[image]

You see, the image is on the left side and the text is below the image.

What can I do to make the output right also on Outlook email clients?

Comment: This is complicated topic, look here on general guidelines why what you're doing will not work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61633896/css-email-template-at-outlook-does-not-display-correctly/61634695#61634695

Comment: @Anastazy I updated my question: I'm using `Email On Acid` to test and it's working on most email clients, but not on the Outlook clients mentioned above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally ended up with this code, that is working also on Outlook:

```
<center>

<!--[if !mso]><!-->
<table style="background-color:red;max-width:600px;height:140px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;border-spacing:0px;">
<!--<![endif]-->
<!--[if mso]>
<table style="background-color:red;width:600px;height:140px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;border-spacing:0px;align:center;">
<![endif]-->

<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="margin:0;font-size:30px;font-weight:700;padding-left:10px;width:100%;">This is an important example header!</td>
<td style="margin:0px;padding:0px;"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/140x99" height="140" width="99" style="height:140px;width:99px;border:0;margin:0px;padding:0px;display:block;"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

</center>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply `align="right"` on image.

Note: I am not 100% sure if it'll work, since I don't have access to Email on Acid at the moment.

```
<div style="background-color:red;max-width:600px;height:140px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">

<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/140x99" align="right" height="140" width="99"
style="height:140px;width:99px;display:block;border:0;float:right;margin:0px;padding:0px;">

<p style="margin:0;font-size:30px;font-weight:700;padding-left:10px;margin-top:0px;padding-top:10px;">This is an important example header!</p>

</div>
```

Comment: This isn't really working. The image stays on the right side but the red element is only as height as the text is. I changed my code to use `<table>` instead of `<div>` and `<p>`. (This is the recommended way for HTML emails, isn't it?) I'll post the working code here later.

Comment: Yeah, just use tables, I was going to recommend that. I thought setting align might do the trick.

Comment: Okay, thanks! Did it and posted my working code here.