# Max width property not working on outlook desktop app version, while doing fine on web version?

Tags: html, css, html-email, email-templates

I have a div container that has 480px max in width, the container has a white background

this is the code ( ugly, email templates :) ) :

```
<body style="
        font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 12px;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        background-color: #f5f5f5;
        box-sizing: border-box;">
    <div style="max-width: 500px; 
        margin: 0 auto;">
        <table style="
        border-collapse: collapse;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        font-family: Arial, sans-serif;">
            <tbody style="width: 100%; background-color: #fff;box-sizing: border-box;
        font-family: Arial, sans-serif;">
                <!-- LOGO Section -->
                <tr pardot-region="”NAMEOFREGION”" pardot-removable="”NAMEOFSECTION”"
                    pardot-repeatable="”NAMEOFSECTION”"
                    style="width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box; font-family: Arial, sans-serif;">
                    <td style="background-color: #f5f5f5;text-align: center; box-sizing: border-box;
                font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
                padding: 20px; "><a href="{{View_Online}}" style="font-size:14px; color: #707070;">Afficher dans le
                            navigateur</a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr pardot-region="”NAMEOFREGION”" pardot-removable="”NAMEOFSECTION”"
                    pardot-repeatable="”NAMEOFSECTION”"
                    style="width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box; font-family: Arial, sans-serif;">
                    <td style="background-color: #fff; text-align: center; box-sizing: border-box; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; padding: 30px 0; "><img alt="naef logo"
                            src="https://wvw.naef.ch/l/881863/2021-02-08/mnkj/881863/1612788567SGb7N34S/logo.png" style="max-width: 125px; box-sizing: border-box;
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;"></td>
         .
         .
         .
         .
         .
         .
         .
         .
         .
         .
```

so the table has content inside, images, texts, etc .. & there are many images that are not respecting the 100% width, they go outside their box, so the contaiber shrinked too even though I am settin the max width property !

Here is the result on outlook web for example : a body with f5f5f5 background & inside it there is a white container, so normal and expected!

[image]

For the  application here is tthe schoking results :

[image]

Anyone has an idea ? I am new to this email templates, and my brain is about to blow up :D, I would like to have some guide & help.

Any help ofc would be much appreciated.

Comment: does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61634695/8134014)  answers your question ?

Comment: a little bit yes, max-width won't work since it is html 5, I have to adapt this with html4 only ! Thank you & Thanks to Outlook!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS Email Template at Outlook does not display correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61633896/css-email-template-at-outlook-does-not-display-correctly)