# How can I send HTML with BOOTSTRAP email

Tags: php, html, bootstrap-4

How do I send HTML email so that it will look nice with Bootstrap 4? When I send mail it looks nice, but when receiver gets it it looks bad.
here's code:

https://jsfiddle.net/bluemilkyh/6m4v9pnf/1/

I'd also like to make footer form (it's about news subscription) when they fill the form and press the button it would save to my database (I have database already which is not localhost...).

code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Stanovanja Fink</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>

<!-- navbar -->
 
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
<a class="navbar-brand" href="http://localhost/stanovanjefink/index.php">Stanovanja Fink</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="http://localhost/stanovanjefink/stanovanjeanja.php">Stanovanje Anja</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="http://localhost/stanovanjefink/stanovanjealjaz.php">Stanovanje Aljaž</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="http://localhost/stanovanjefink/kontakt.php">Kontakt</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    </form>
 </div>
</nav>
<hr>
<body>
<div class="p-3 mb-2 bg-light text-dark container text-center d-flex flex-column align-items-center">
<h2 form-inline justify-content-center>Rezervacija Stanovanje Aljaz</h2>
<br>
<br>
<label ><b>Ime: </b></label>
    <input type="text" class=" form-control col-sm-6 " disabled value="" >
<label><b>Priimek: </b></label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control col-sm-6 " disabled value="" ><label><b>Telefon: </b></label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control col-sm-6" disabled value="">
<label><b>E-mail: </b></label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control col-sm-6" disabled value="">
<label><b>Prihod: </b></label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control col-sm-6" disabled value="">
<label><b>Odhod: </b></label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control col-sm-6" disabled value="">
<label><b>Cena: </b></label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control col-sm-6" disabled value="">
<br>
<h3>Informacije </h3>
<p><i class="gdlr-icon fa fa-map-marker"></i><b> Lokacija:</b> Pod Lipovim trotom</p>
<p><i class="gdlr-icon fa fa-phone"></i> <b>Telefon:</b> +36 41 8813 49219  </p>
<p><i class="gdlr-icon fa fa-envelope"></i> <b>Email :</b> +36 41 88213 49912  </p>
<br>
</div>
</body>
<footer class="bg-dark text-center">
  <div class="container p-4">
      <form action="kontakt.php">  
        <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
          <div class="col-auto">
            <p class="pt-2" style="color:white;">
              <b>Naroci se na novice: </b>
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-5 col-12">   
            <div class="form-outline form-white mb-4">
              <input type="email" placeholder="email" name="novice" class="form-control" required>
            </div>
          </div>    
          <div class="col-auto">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-light mb-4">
              Narocite se
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <section class="mb-4">
      <a class="btn btn-outline-light btn-floating m-1" href="#!" role="button"
        ><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i
      ></a>
      <a class="btn btn-outline-light btn-floating m-1" href="#!" role="button"
        ><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i
      ></a>
      <a class="btn btn-outline-light btn-floating m-1" href="#!" role="button"
        ><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>  
    </section>
      </form>
  </div>
  <div class="text-center p-3" style="background-color:black; color:gray;">
    © 2020 Stanovanja Fink
  </div>
  </div>
</footer>`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing you are using [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/). Use [bootstrap for e-mail](https://bootstrapemail.com/docs/introduction) instead. Web frameworks will NOT play nicely with e-mail. HTML e-mail have different rules and best practices on how to develop markup for it, than classic web sites.

Possibly related:

- Look for the top answer here to get a general idea about developing for e-mail: [CSS Email Template at Outlook does not display correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61633896/css-email-template-at-outlook-does-not-display-correctly/61634695#61634695)
- Here for basic layout: [How to make a fluid width email with a max width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30485328/how-to-make-a-fluid-width-email-with-a-max-width/30492292#30492292)